# How do you limit what gets exported from a c# dll?

Tags: c#, dllexport

I have a dll that I only want certain classes to be exported.  In C++, you can use the class __declspec(dllexport) ClassName ... Is there a C# equivalent?

Comment: marking classes internal would conceal it from used by external applications. But is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mark the types/members that you want to be externally available as `public`, and the things you don't want to export as either `internal`, or (where available - members and nested types) `private`. If unspecified, top-level classes default to `internal`, and methods default to `private`.

Comment: Don't forget that all base (and otherwise related) types for public types need to be public as well.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ fortunately the compiler doesn't let you forget ;p

Answer (score 3):

You make your classes private or internal.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are saying... then I think that's the difference between public and internal/private classes.

Only public classes are visible outside an assembly (DLL).

Answer (score -1):

Would MEF be the route that you want to go.. check out the link not sure if this will help

[Managed Extensibility Framework Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx)
 this will be a way of exporting